# jQuery issue - Same Origin preventing access to same-domain iFrame?

Tags: jquery, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to pull some data from server.com/sso/index.jsp into server.com/mobile/

I can include my iFrame fine:

```
var $ssoFrame= $( '<iframe id="sso" name="sso" style="width:0px; height:0px; border: 0px"    
src="/sso/index.jsp"></iframe>' );
$( ".someDiv" ).first().append( $ssoFrame);
```

And I can inspect the contents in Chrome. However, if I run this in console:

```
$("#sso").contents();
```

I get this:

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here - how / why is this a cross-origin request when it's on the same server (and even called without specifying a domain in the src?). Getting any changes made to /sso/index.jsp is going to be a nightmare, so I'm hoping there's a way I can analyse its contents through this iFrame instead. I tried something with $.get and got blocked there too - could it be a http vs https mismatch on the defaults for .com/mobile/ vs .com/sso/index.jsp?

Appreciate any ideas!

Sam

Comment: It looks to me like you need to get the `contentWindow` for the iFrame and do your jQuery query from there to find the contents of that other document.  You're trying to find things in the iFrame, but that's what is in the parent document, not the subdocument loaded into the iFrame.  And, yes https/http will ALSO create a same-origin issue.  You must be using the EXACT same protocol and domain (including subdomain).

Answer (score 0):

> This is a security update. If an attacker can modify some file in the
>   web server (the JS one, for example), he can make every loaded pages
>   to download another script (for example to keylog your password or
>   steal your SessionID and send it to his own server).
>
> To avoid it, the browser check the Same-origin policy
>
> Your problem is that the browser is trying to load something with your
>   script (with an Ajax request) that is on another domain (or
>   subdomain). To avoid it (if it is on your own website) you can:

take a look at [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin)